# Import SVG from file and add it to bundle in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, svg, import, angular-cli

I'm looking for an optimal way to author the icons library for Angular framework.

We want end developer to be able to import individual icons from the library and inline them in their templates. The imported icons should be added directly to the application's bundle (instead of fetching them individually by URL) and unused icons shouldn't bloat the bundle (e.g. by using Tree Shaking friendly approach).

The most straightforward approach would be to create an individual component for each icon and embed the SVG content directly to the component's template. However, this would require a lot of authoring work to produce/maintain these components, so it's not a very convenient approach. Also, such components would only work in Angular, but we want to make the library somewhat framework agnostic.

The best solution would be to load SVG content directly from the individual SVG files and embed the content to the application bundle and then to output the content, probably using a single dynamic component.

However, is there a way to actually import SVG-file and add it to the build using only Angular CLI?

The task seems trivial with Webpack, but we can't access the Webpack configuration in Angular CLI directly.

Comment: The popular approach seems to be to create a font for your icons. As exemple, the Material Icon font.

Comment: Font is not an option, the current approach is to use inline SVG images, because you can customize them with CSS, manipulate them with JS. Also, with fonts you have to load all icons from the library at once (tree shaking will not help here).